# Center flex layout without shrinking the column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a grid inside of a flexbox with `flex-flow` set to `column nowrap`. The grid doesn't have a fixed number of columns `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 270px)`.

My problem is that when I'm trying to center that grid in the flexbox, it doesn't take up as much space as possible, and instead just reduces the number of columns to 1.

I want the grid to have 4 columns unless it's about to overflow from the container. How do I achieve that? I tried to set `margin: 0 auto;` on the grid, but it produces the same result.

*Current result:*
[image]

*Desired result + the columns have to wrap instead of overflowing:* 
[image]

**HTML/CSS**
I've set `min-width: 300px` for the grid because it contains pictures with width of `270px + 10px` gap. And I've set `max-width: calc(4 * 280px)` because I don't want to have more than 4 columns.

```css
.portfolio {
  min-height: 1004px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.portfolio-heading {
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #616161;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-text {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #616161;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-nav-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 60px 0px 15px 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.portfolio-nav-row-btn {
  padding: 10px 19px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ff6760;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ff6760;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-grid {
  max-width: calc(4 * 280px);
  min-width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 270px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <h1 class="portfolio-heading">Our Featured Works</h1>
  <p class="portfolio-text">Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
  <div class="portfolio-nav-row">
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn all-btn" type="button">All</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn graphic-btn" type="button">Graphic</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn illustration-btn" type="button">Illustration</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn motion-btn" type="button">Motion</button>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-grid">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column1" src="pictures/portfolio-1.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column2" src="pictures/portfolio-2.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column3" src="pictures/portfolio-3.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column4" src="pictures/portfolio-4.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column1" src="pictures/portfolio-5.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column2" src="pictures/portfolio-6.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column3" src="pictures/portfolio-7.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column4" src="pictures/portfolio-8.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column1" src="pictures/portfolio-9.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column2" src="pictures/portfolio-10.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column3" src="pictures/portfolio-11.png" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column4" src="pictures/portfolio-12.png" alt="portfolio image">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `width: 100%` on `.portfolio-grid`. It takes only one column because you don't give it any width. So it takes its width depending on it `min-width` value. I have check it on my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Yeasin01/pen/GxQKRG) and it's working fine with `width: 100%`.

```css
.portfolio {
  min-height: 1004px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.portfolio-heading {
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #616161;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-text {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #616161;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-nav-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 60px 0px 15px 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.portfolio-nav-row-btn {
  padding: 10px 19px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ff6760;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ff6760;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-grid {
  max-width: calc(4 * 280px);
  min-width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <h1 class="portfolio-heading">Our Featured Works</h1>
  <p class="portfolio-text">Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
  <div class="portfolio-nav-row">
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn all-btn" type="button">All</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn graphic-btn" type="button">Graphic</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn illustration-btn" type="button">Illustration</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn motion-btn" type="button">Motion</button>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-grid">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column1" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column2" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column3" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column4" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column1" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column2" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column3" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column4" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column1" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column2" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column3" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column4" src="http://placehold.it/270x270" alt="portfolio image">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It is initially centered when there are 4 columns, but when there are 3 or less the grid it aligns to the left.

Comment: use justify-content: center; and it will be center. event if it become 2 or 3 column. see the link https://codepen.io/Yeasin01/pen/GxQKRG

Comment: okay, this works now. and it is the most minimal solution. i'm accepting this answer instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Switch from `column nowrap` to `row wrap` on the main container. Then force each item to occupy the full row with `flex-basis: 100%`. Horizontal centering then becomes simple and easy.

Here's your code with revisions. I removed some visual styles that weren't relevant to the problem.

```css
.portfolio {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.portfolio-heading { flex-basis: 100%; }
.portfolio-text    { flex-basis: 100%; }

.portfolio-nav-row {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.portfolio-nav-row-btn {
  padding: 10px 19px;
  background-color: #ff6760;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portfolio-nav-row-btn+.portfolio-nav-row-btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.portfolio-grid {
  max-width: calc(4 * 280px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 270px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <h1 class="portfolio-heading">Our Featured Works</h1>
  <p class="portfolio-text">Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
  <div class="portfolio-nav-row">
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn all-btn" type="button">All</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn graphic-btn" type="button">Graphic</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn illustration-btn" type="button">Illustration</button>
    <button class="portfolio-nav-row-btn motion-btn" type="button">Motion</button>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-grid">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column1" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column2" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column3" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row1-column4" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column1" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column2" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column3" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row2-column4" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column1" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column2" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column3" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
    <img class="portfolio-grid-item portfolio-grid-row3-column4" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="270" alt="portfolio image">
  </div>
</section>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmvt3zfu/)

Comment: This solution only works initially when there are 4 columns. It aligns to the left when there are 3 columns or less. However, if i change my `.portfolio-grid` rule to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));` , as @Ravan suggested, it does center the grid. But does so by adding the gaps between items. I need a solution with fixed gap size.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome, my solution keeps the columns centered in all screen sizes.

Comment: oh, yeah, this works, sorry. I didn't notice that you changed `.portfolio-grid`'s `justify-items` to `justify-content`. I'll recheck it a couple more time and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your flexbox container (`.portfolio`), remove `align-items:center` and note that flexbox uses `justify-content` and not `justify-items`. This seems to do the job.

```
.portfolio {
    min-height: 1004px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osayky9b/

Edit: Centered grid: https://jsfiddle.net/osayky9b/8/

Comment: Change your `.portfolio-grid` rule to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));` ?? Updated the fiddle link.

Comment: nope. it is centered initially, but when you increase the width it just aligns to the left. and also, i'd prefer my items to be exactly 270px wide.

Comment: in your jsfiddle, try to stretch the result window all the way to the left. it aligns to the left for me.

Comment: Right on! That's because of your max-width property on portfolio grid.

Comment: well, it has to be set, because i need there to be no more than 4 columns in the grid.